# flatpickr minDate does not respect blocked weekends

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I opened up a [github issue](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/2945) already but since there seems to be no activity, I'll ask here and hope someone can help me out.

#### Current Situation

I am using [flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) for a Date selection where I need to block the weekends and have a lead time set up.

When blocking weekends like this:

```
'disable': [
    function(date) {
        // blocking Sunday (0) and Saturday (6)
        return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }
],
```

and setting up a lead time of 4 days like that (today and the following 3 days blocked):

```
// blocking today + 3 following days
minDate: new Date().fp_incr(4)
```

the date picker does not behave as expected.

#### Expectation: Weekends are blocked.

When on a **Wednesday** selecting a date, the first option should be **Tuesday** since today and the following 3 days (Wed–Mon, excl. weekends) are blocked.

#### Actual behaviour: Weekends are not blocked for minDate.

When on a **Wednesday** selecting a date, the first option is **Sunday** because the weekend is included in the count. But then, the Weekend blocker steps in and actually blocks the weekend from being picked (as expected), so the first possible day is the following **Monday**.

It doesn't change anything if the minDate option comes before or after the disable one.

with weekends blocked:
[image: with weekends blocked]

without weekends blocked:
[image: without weekends blocked]

#### Version

flatpickr 4.6.13

Any recommendations are appreciated. I use this with plain Javascript and Blazor. Does anyone know how to overwrite the minDate or insert a function into the minDate option to recognise the blocked days?
Best would be to have the minDate option recognize and respect the disable option.

Comment: Guess it should work if you set the minDate to the next available day _after_ the weekend?

Comment: minDate is set to today + 3 days. It's dependent on what day today is. It's not always the day after the weekend.

Comment: If you mean I should add this to my lead time, then please tell me how.

Comment: On Tuesday +4 would land you on Saturday, so add 6 instead to land on Monday. On Wednesday, you land on Sunday, so add 5 instead. Monday plus 4 lands you on Friday, that is okay to begin with - and so are Thursday through to Sunday, which plus 4 will all land you on a weekday.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, so could I write sth like minDate: function(date) { if(date.getDay() === 2) { //add 6} elseif(date.getDay() === 3) { //add 5} else { //add 4} } ?

Comment: okay no so minDate only accepts a string or a date.

Comment: Just make it `minDate: new Date().fp_incr(daysToAdvance)` then, and see to it that you assign the correct value to `daysToAdvance` beforehand ...

Comment: Although `minDate: function() {...}` should probably also work, you just need to make sure that function _returns_ a date object or date string.

Comment: @CBroe it seems that once flatpickr is initialised, it doesn't accept changed variables afterwards. Or at least I can't get it to work that way.

Comment: So I got it working now, by setting the default lead time value `leadtime = 4`, then get the lead time as a string with `leadtimeString = new Date().fp_incr(leadtime).toString();`, then check if the String contains "Sat" or "Sun" with e.g. `if (leattimeString.includes('Sat')) {}`, and then initialise the flatpickr again with the correct `minDate`option. Sounds dirty, looks dirty, but does what I want.

Comment: @CBroe `minDate: function() {...}` is not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Thats what I got working:

1. I set the default lead time value in a variable to 4
2. I convert the date + leadtime to a string which gives me `Sun Oct 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200`
3. I then check if the String contains "Sat" or "Sun"
4. I then initialise the flatpickr with the correct `minDate` option. (+2 for the weekend count)

```
var leadtime = 4;
var leattimeString = new Date().fp_incr(leadtime).toString();

if (leattimeString.includes('Sat') || leattimeString.includes('Sun')) {
    flatpickr('.js-flatpickr', {
        ...
        // when leadtime lands on a Saturday or Sunday add 2 extra days to count the weekend
        minDate: new Date().fp_incr(6),
    })
}
```

[image]

Sounds dirty, looks dirty, but does what I want.

It doesn't seem to work to initialise flatpickr first and then have the correct lead time inserted afterwards.
It also doesn't work to use `minDate: function  {..}`

Thanks to @CBroe for pushing me into the right direction.